# Random Sample Dataset Generator

Tags: r, dataset

I want to do some time series analysis in R to analyze the inventory movement problem. 
Say take a snapshot of local grocery's inventory every day. Today, there are 100 unit cucumber and the unitPrice is 1.2$/unit, also they have 500 unit tomato and the unitPrice is 1.5$/unit...etc. Then tomorrow, you take another snapshots of their inventory, they have 50 unit cucumber and the unitPrice is 1.5$/unit, and ....

I am wondering is there some public datasets similar available somewhere? If not, is there sometool or package in R to easily generate some fake dataset so I can get started with the coding part first.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get your random prices and unit numbers using `rnorm` and `runif` with appropriate arguments to specify the ranges that make sense in your simulation.  If you are having issues with incrementing the dates automatically, look at the `lubridate` package.